# Flipping Output Logic

Tags: voltage-divider, opto-isolator, comparator

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]
<sub>(source: [siteonlinetest.com](http://coldtears.lin3.siteonlinetest.com/files/speed-2.jpg))</sub>

The diagram above has a pot between VCC, LM393 and Ground, on my board pictured below this is replaced by a voltage divider with two 10k pots.

It looks like this: (Front)

[image: photo]

The logic is currently as follows:

- VCC=5v
- Output=5v (obstructed), floating (open).

I need to flip the output logic and haven't had much luck in doing this. This board is the perfect form factor for my application and I would like to keep it if possible. Is there something simple I can add to it to accomplish this?

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, the pot on the schematic is replaced by two fixed resistors on the board.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to a soldering iron with a very fine tip, and some very fine solder and wire (say, 30 ga):

1 - desolder pins 2 and 3 of the comparator

2 - bend the pins up as far as you can without breaking them (the tip of an xacto knife will work)

3 - using the fine wire, swap the pins' connections to the pc board pads

4 - use a drop of 5-minute epoxy to insulate the pins and jumper wires.

This will reverse the logic of your output.

Be careful not to leave any solder bridges.

Comment: First of all Pins 2 and 3 are not connected to anything. The IC LM393 is only connected on 4-8. Following your suggestion for the b side of this chip I flipped Pins 5 and 6 and we are now closer to the goal but not quite there. Here is how the logic looks now:
Opto Open: 3.7v (Good, this will work),
Opto Closed: Very low float (Close but I need it to be zero so it mimics a mechanical switch)

Answer (score 2):

Connect the output to the nOE input of a 74AHC1G125 with a pull-down resistor. Tie the A input high. Y should then have H and Hi-Z flipped from the output.

Comment: The other solution did not work so I am now looking at what you suggested. Building this now...

Comment: Killed the circuit, The cheap board couldn't take the abuse of being re-worked 4+ times. Oh well. Looks like I am going to have to design something from scratch.